# ASP.NET MVC Razor with Layout - CSS linked but not applied

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I started a Asp.net MVC project and created a main layout and created bundle css groups. Every subpage will have one more css which I need to link on the subpage. So, I bundle all the css from the main page and then the css group on the subpage. On one page it is working, on another it is not. Three hours, nothing found. When I try the code without the main layout, it's working. I tried even to create embedded css on that subpage, but even that was not working. The main css files are working, but the one included on the subpage is linked (and the link is ok) but not applied.

Main page (layout):

```
    @Styles.Render("~/css/main")
    @RenderSection("head", false)
```

Subpage:

```
@section head{
@Styles.Render("~/css/account") }
```

Bundle:

```
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/css/main").Include(
                    "~/assets/css/bootstrap.css",
                    "~/assets/css/metisMenu.css",
                    "~/assets/css/font-awesome.css",
                    "~/assets/css/elegant-icons.css",
                    "~/assets/css/pe-7-icons.css",
                    "~/assets/css/pe-7-icons-helper.css",
                    "~/assets/css/jquery-jvectormap.css",
                    "~/assets/css/tether-shepherd.css",
                    "~/assets/css/jstree-default.css",
                    "~/assets/css/styles.css",
                    "~/assets/css/custom.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/css/account").Include("~/assets/css/account.css"));
```

I'm using this template: http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB051SCJ1
So, I created the layout and the subpage was account settings (Click on account and then settings).

Anybody ideas what is the problem?

Comment: just to note that if you are using `Html.RenderPartial` to render a partial view you can't include `@section` in these partial views

Comment: I added a View and chose the Layout. And then I'm using sections, so it's not partial. In the meantime I tried several subpages, every is working except this one!!! Is there any css that MVC cannot render??

Comment: look at the page source and see if these files are rendered into your view; if they are, you might have something mistyped in your css such as a selector

Comment: Make sure that all the file paths are correct. If the bundler cannot find a referenced file, it just silently ignores it.

Comment: When I go to source view and try to open the layout css files and the one subpage css, every css can be opened and seems that everything is ok.
When I just paste the whole HTML code (layout + subpage) without using a layout, everything works. :(

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help.
The problem was that in the template are on every page added new classes above the container. I always made master pages with container from body, but this time I have to make it for the whole body. :(

Thank you!